# Python adjust scale intensity at confusion matrix plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I have a number of confusion matrix plots with numbers not summing up to the same sum (the numbers are out of 100 for a benchmark)
Please see attached example image below:
[confusion matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wLZW.png)
I do not want the 22 and the 32 have the same color intensity, but be at the same scale from 0 to 100 intensity levels.
How can I adjust the scale in python given the following used code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, ConfusionMatrixDisplay

cm = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, labels=["Up", "Down"])
disp = ConfusionMatrixDisplay(confusion_matrix=cm,display_labels=["Up", "Down"])
disp.plot(cmap="OrRd")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
disp.ax_.get_images()[0].set_clim(0, 100)
```

And the full code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, ConfusionMatrixDisplay

cm = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, labels=["Up", "Down"])

disp = ConfusionMatrixDisplay(confusion_matrix=cm,display_labels=["Up", "Down"])
disp.plot(cmap="OrRd")

disp.ax_.get_images()[0].set_clim(0, 100)
```